# how define method that get an argument that is a pointer other method in java android

Tags: android

I need to define some method that the argument is some pointer of other method ( in different class ( with specific signature )

How can i do it on android ( java ) ?

Comment: You can not, See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value lets go with @Juan suggestion I believe there is an alternative for your problem!

Comment: In Java you don't have pointers as in C. Perhaps if you explain what you want to resolve there is another way arround someone could sugest.

Comment: @ Juan :: I know, but i need to give an argument like pointer .. reference to some other method

Comment: Not in Java I guess! @Yanshof